# Lotus Notes Message : "DBD cannot get the list of adress books for the local server"

Tags: lotus-notes

One of my Louts Notes user is getting  as strange message. When he is trying to access the address book by using  any of the Notes applicaitons, Instead of showing up the address book names in the address dialog he is getting the following error message in the dialog window , it is rendering as "DBD cannot get the list of adress books for the local server".

What does this message mean and Why this meesage shows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few [posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22DBD%20cannot%20get%20the%20list%22%20of%20address%20books%20for%20the%20local%20server) about this, pointing to missing spr/apar's.

Check the Preferences-> Local address books and make sure that the user has access to all the databases mentioned there.

Comment: In this case my user Local Names.nsf got corrupted. I refreshed the design and recreated the connection documents. Now it started working... Thank you.